# Material-ui React components not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use http://www.material-ui.com/ for front end design. I am trying to execute the first example within the getting started tutorial. I have following html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>examples</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="App.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyAwesomeReactComponent.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and following App.js and MyAwesomeReactComponent.js files as defined in ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage )

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

MyAwesomeReactComponent.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const MyAwesomeReactComponent = () => (
  <RaisedButton label="Default" />
);

export default MyAwesomeReactComponent;
```

But when I run the index file, I can't see any output.

Comment: Did you check if some errors come from the console? Any chance you could make a base fiddle with your example? Or somewhere where we could quickly "remake" your little example? Do you have react as part of your packages?

Comment: to me it looks like you are not using babael/webpack and so on..

Comment: @PraveenPrasad , I am a beginner. And I get stuck since the tutorials has not guided on those things? What should I set up before starting it? or any references ?

Comment: You're doing it wrong way. You need to setup babel + browserify or webpack for make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here since you are implementing ES6 code, you need to use a javascript compiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transform your ES6 code to ES5 which is current javascript standard that is supported by browsers.

It would be a good practice to use babel with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) as a loader.

Following [React's get started page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html)'s instruction is a good starting point. I'd suggest reading the instructions carefully.

Finally, if you want to use pure ES6 without transforming, the compatibility table is available here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/